# When my movie is finished to play, the app crashes

Tags: objective-c, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller

I tried to launch a movie by clicking in a button. When I click the Movie player appears and works fine. The movie plays until the end and the Movie player disappears. After it disappears, my app crashes...

I use my View Controller in Tab Bar Application with this code :

```
- (void)moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification *) aNotification{

    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [aNotification object];
    [player setFullscreen:NO animated:YES];
    [player.view removeFromSuperview];
    [player stop];
    player.initialPlaybackTime = -1.0;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:player];
    [player release];
    player=nil;
}

- (IBAction)playVideo:(UIButton *)playButton{
    NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Teaser 04" ofType:@"mov"];
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]];
    player.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    player.view.frame = CGRectMake(0., 44., self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height-44);
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:player];
    [self.view addSubview:player.view];
    [player play];
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I just want configure a button that start the video and when the video is finished, the MoviePlayer View disappears and the app come back to my initial .xib

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, I don't know if it is the best but for what I want it's working :

```
- (void)movieFinishedCallBack:(NSNotification *) aNotification{
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [aNotification object];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:player];
[player.view removeFromSuperview];
[player stop];
[player release];
```

}

```
- (IBAction)playVideo:(UIButton *)playButton{
NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Teaser 04" ofType:@"mov"];
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallBack:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:player];
player.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 950, 600);
[self.view addSubview:player.view];
[player play];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but my guess is that the player gets used somewhere in the backtrace for the call to moviePlayBackDidFinish: ... If I'm right, then deallocing the object there - which it looks like you're doing - is bad news, since the object is still needed somewhere up in the stack.

Check out this post for more details: [How to release MPMoviePlayerController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695307/how-to-release-mpmovieplayercontroller)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but it's not about this. I switch the function moviePlayBackDidFinish by movieFinishedCallBack

Comment: He is not deallocating the player but releasing it.

Comment: Isn't he effectively deallocating it by calling "release" there?