# iPhone Memory leak issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks

I have the following code in my iPhone application, warning memory leak!

**This is my code**

```
-(IBAction)playVideo:(id)sender  {  
     NSString *filepath   =   [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" 
                                                              ofType:@"mov"];  
     NSURL    *fileURL    =   [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];  
     MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
    [moviePlayerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(38, 100, 250, 163)];  
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];  
    moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;  
    [moviePlayerController play];  
}
```

This is the error message I'm getting:
**Potential leak of an object allocated on line 37 and stored into 'moviePlayerController'**

I did try to autorelease "moviePlayerController" and then I try to release it. Both cases memory leak was solved but the video didn't play on the iPhone! Strange please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to release MPMoviePlayerController?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695307/how-to-release-mpmovieplayercontroller)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The warning is correct: you are leaking the `MPMoviePlayerController` instance. But as you've discovered, you can't effectively use the view without keeping the controller around.

The solution is to store the `MPMoviePlayerController` into an ivar/property in your class, and then release it when you are done with its view (e.g. in `viewDidUnload` and `dealloc`).

Answer (score 0):

try adding `MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController` in your header file

then `@property (nonatomic, retain) MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController;`

then in your .m file `@synthesize moviePlayerController;`

then try `self.moviePlayerController = [[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL] autorelease];`

lastly add `self.moviePlayerController = nil` and `[moviePlayerController release]` to your `viewDidUnload` and `dealloc`.