# iOS 6, Xcode 4.5 video not exiting when done playing

Tags: xcode, ios6, xcode4.5

I am using this code to play a video on iOS 6:

```
-(void)GrommeVideo4
{
NSURL *url5 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                      pathForResource:@"Flickers" ofType:@"mp4"]];
grommePlayer4 =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                  initWithContentURL:url5];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayerWillExitFullscreen:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification
                                           object:nil];

grommePlayer4.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
grommePlayer4.shouldAutoplay = YES;
[self.view addSubview:grommePlayer4.view];
[grommePlayer4 setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
}

-(void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification *)aNotification{
[grommePlayer4.view removeFromSuperview];
grommePlayer4 = nil;
}


- (void)moviePlayerWillExitFullscreen:(NSNotification*) aNotification {
[grommePlayer4 stop];
[grommePlayer4.view removeFromSuperview];
grommePlayer4 = nil;
}
```

And I can press "Done" to exit the video at any time, and it works fine, but when I watch the video through to the end, it just displays a black screen. Any ideas as to why this could occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, hope it helps

```
-(void)GrommeVideo4
{
    NSURL *url5 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                      pathForResource:@"Flickers" ofType:@"mp4"]];
    grommePlayer4 =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                  initWithContentURL:url5];

    grommePlayer4.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
    grommePlayer4.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:grommePlayer4.view];
    [grommePlayer4 setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
}

-(void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification *)aNotification{
    [grommePlayer4.view removeFromSuperview];
    grommePlayer4 = nil;
}


- (void)moviePlayerWillExitFullscreen:(NSNotification*) aNotification {
    [grommePlayer4 stop];
    [grommePlayer4.view removeFromSuperview];
    grommePlayer4 = nil;
}
```

Comment: But wont I need to call the moviePlayBackDIdFinish using this line:


`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:nil];`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to also stop the player in moviePlayBackDidFinish?

Comment: Yes, I tried that and it had no effect, it still displayed the black screen.

Comment: Found this...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695307/how-to-release-mpmovieplayercontroller

Comment: We cannot use autorelease or release anymore, this question was from 2009, I haven't been able to find anything newer.

Comment: just don't put autorelease/release code. it's done automatically by arc